# What is the benefit of NULL values in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, null

I'm trying to understand how Oracle handles NULL values. This is really more of a request for confirmation of what I've already discovered, to make sure I haven't overlooked something obvious. Below are scripts to confirm that Oracle handles NULL values the same as it handles a blank string. If such is the case, then pray tell why would any Oracle database be developed to ever allow a field to be NULL, other than to introduce obfuscation to an index when querying against it (i.e. ... WHERE NVL(FieldName,'Default Value') != 'test')???

```
-- Returns only 2 rows
-- Oracle doesn't differentiate from blank strings and NULL values
SELECT NULL AS Test_Nulls from dual
UNION
SELECT '' AS Test_Nulls from dual
UNION
SELECT 'Test' AS Test_Nulls from dual;

-- Returns "X"
-- Further proof Oracle doesn't differentiate from blank strings and NULL values
SELECT 'X' AS Test_Nulls
FROM dual
WHERE '' is NULL;

-- Returns "X"
-- Even further proof Oracle doesn't differentiate from blank strings and NULL values
SELECT NVL('','X') AS Test_Nulls
FROM dual;

-- Returns 3 rows
-- Oracle recognizes <Carriage Return> + <Line Feed>
SELECT '' AS Returned from dual
UNION
SELECT '
' AS Returned FROM dual
UNION
SELECT 'Test' AS Returned FROM dual;
```

Comment: Null is indeed (almost) the same as empty string, but only for string data types. A number or a date can also be null, and in that case null is not an empty string (it doesn't even have the same data type). There are a lot of people, me included, who are very unhappy with Oracle's interpretation of null for strings as being the same as an empty string - this violates all the principles of relational theory and the SQL standard. Oracle keeps saying in the future they "may" follow the SQL standard with the data type VARCHAR, but I am not holding my breath. Confirmed!

Comment: Agreed, Oracle's support for NULLs is poor, but grounded in very old history and unlikely to change now. You just get used to it. NULLable columns are generally used for optional fields, and/or to allow storing rows with incomplete (unknown or yet-to-be-determined) data.

Comment: Any new designs for VarChar2 and nVarChar2 fields in Oracle will be done as NOT NULL with a default of ''

Answer (score 0):

Simple Answer: For any new database design work I do in Oracle, I will set all my varchar2 and nvarchar2 and char2 and nchar2 fields to not allow NULL and to have a default value of an empty string. I have always been suspicious of the naming convention of adding a "2" suffix, and the fact that it is not a common field type to other database platforms. To me, it seems like a last-minute desperate means that Oracle handled a situation in their early days like, "Oh well, ... we can't make it right, so we'll just give it a new name!" That's my 2-cents on this matter.